# how to render links as menu tabs

Tags: 7, routes

I have created a block that generates some links. I want to display these links as menu tabs in my website. This is the php code I have written inside block.

```
<?php
  $current_url = current_path();
  $param = explode("/", $current_url);
  $nid = $param[1];

  $type = db_select("node", "n")
            ->fields("n", array("type"))
            ->condition("nid", $nid, "=")
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAssoc();

  switch($type['type']) {
    case "description":
      $current_desc_link = $current_url;
      $current_demo_link = db_select("field_data_field_desc_demolink", "fddd")
                          ->fields("fddd", array("field_desc_demolink_url"))
                          ->condition("entity_id", $nid, "=")
                          ->execute()
                          ->fetchAssoc();

      $howto_entityid = db_select("field_data_field_howto_demolink", "fdhd")
                          ->fields("fdhd", array("entity_id"))
                          ->condition("field_howto_demolink_url", $current_demo_link['field_desc_demolink_url'], "=")
                          ->execute()
                          ->fetchAssoc();

      $current_howto_link = "node/" . $howto_entityid;

      break;

    case "how_to":
      $current_howto_link = $current_url;
      $current_demo_link = db_select("field_data_field_howto_demolink", "fdhd")
                          ->fields("fdhd", array("field_howto_demolink_url"))
                          ->condition("entity_id", $nid, "=")
                          ->execute()
                          ->fetchAssoc();

      $desc_entityid = db_select("field_data_field_desc_demolink", "fddd")
                          ->fields("fddd", array("entity_id"))
                          ->condition("field_desc_demolink_url", $current_demo_link['field_howto_demolink_url'], "=")
                          ->execute()
                          ->fetchAssoc();

      $current_desc_link = "node/" . $desc_entityid;

      break;


    default:
      $desc_entityid = db_select("field_data_field_desc_demolink", "fddd")
                          ->fields("fddd", array("entity_id"))
                          ->condition("field_desc_demolink_url", $current_url, "=")
                          ->execute()
                          ->fetchAssoc();

      $howto_entityid = db_select("field_data_field_howto_demolink", "fdhd")
                          ->fields("fdhd", array("entity_id"))
                          ->condition("field_howto_demolink_url", $current_url, "=")
                          ->execute()
                          ->fetchAssoc();

      $current_demo_link = current_url;
      $current_desc_link = "node/" . $desc_entityid;
      $current_howto_link = "node/" . $howto_entityid;

      break;
}
?>
```

I want to render `$current_demo_link`, `$current_desc_link`, `$current_howto_link` as menu tabs in drupal webiste. I have tried `menu_tree_output` but I have to create menu links in Db. Is there any other way to render the links as menu without converting this as menu links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```
$output = '<ul class="tabs primary">';
$output .= '<li><a href="' . url($current_demo_link) . '">demo link title</a>';
$output .= '<li><a href="' . url($current_desc_link) . '">desc link title</a>'
$output .= '<li><a href="' . url($current_howto_link) . '">hot to link title</a>'
$output .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: simple and a perfect answer